# Elasticsearch how to define persian comma analyzer for a field?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, analyzer, persian

I have defined one language per field inside a type, one of fields may contain comma separated words in different languages, for example i have a field named as `field1` for two language `field1.en` for english and `field1.pr` for Persian.
So how to define custom comma analyzer for `Persian` ?
We can define custom comma analyzer as bellow in normal :

```
"analysis" => [
   "tokenizer" => [
      "comma" => [
         "type" => "pattern",
         "pattern" => ","
      ]
   ],
   "analyzer" => [
      "comma" => [
         "type" => "custom",
         "tokenizer" => "comma"
      ]
   ]
]
```

Suppose in mapping i have a field that should store Persian comma separated words, now how i can define such an anylyzer ? or this comma analyzer will support Persian comma separated words ?

and one another question about `elasticsearch`, how to solve the problem with `Pashto` language ? I have not found any way in elastic to support analyzation of pashto texts.